# convert coordinates DMS to DD

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to turn coordinates from DMS to DD, but I'm confused about the data types I get after exifData returns exif from a photo. What is the correct way to pass this data to the function?

```
void handleSelectPhotos(List<Map<String, dynamic>> selectedPhotos) async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
      allowMultiple: true,
    );

    if (result != null) {
      List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();

      for (File file in files) {
        List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
        Map<String, IfdTag> exifData = await readExifFromBytes(fileBytes);

        // Extract latitude and longitude from exifData
        IfdTag? latitudeTag = exifData['GPS GPSLatitude'];
        IfdTag? longitudeTag = exifData['GPS GPSLongitude'];

        if (latitudeTag != null && longitudeTag != null) {
          double latitude = convertRatiosToDD(latitudeTag.values);
          double longitude = convertRatiosToDD(longitudeTag.values);

          selectedPhotos.add({
            'file': file,
            'latitude': latitude,
            'longitude': longitude,
          });
        }
      }

      print(selectedPhotos);
    }
}

double convertDMSToDD(List<int> coordinates) {
    double degrees = coordinates[0].toDouble();
    double minutes = coordinates[1].toDouble();
    double seconds = coordinates.length > 2 ? coordinates[2].toDouble() : 0.0;

    double dd = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600;
    return dd;
  }
```